# Detecting some text has been selected in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, selection, copy-paste

I've implemented a  notepad application in c#,all the feaures work perfectly,there is  only  one thing which I can't implement exactly.there are some menuitems in the edit dropdown menu,but their enabled property must change according to the situation of the textbox,I have a problem with two situations and I'm looking for an event in order to change their enabled property in this event's eventhandler,here is the problem:

2)When some text is selected in the textbox,delete,copy and paste options should get enabled.how should I detect it?I've tested texchanged event an I've written a condition  like the code below but it didn't work,just the clipboard works well:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.SelectionLength> 0)
            button1.Enabled = false;
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            button2.Enabled = false;


    }
```

How should I solve my problem,by the way I have to use a textbox not a richtextbox.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel, or homework assignment? There's heaps of good notepad alternatives around e.g. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Hint: `MouseUp` event.

Comment: It's just a homework.thanks a lot

Comment: Clipboard.containsText() will not work in your format, Check my edited post again. I think you are aa beginner

Comment: yes actually I'm a beginner,thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Just check SelectionLength in both MouseUp and KeyUp events.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To find out selection

```
if (textbox1.SelectionLength > 0)
{

}
```

For clipboard content, 
use

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.getText();
```

Check clipboard content by,

```
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
// Is Data Text?
if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    label1.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
else
label1.Text = "Data not found.";
```

This is implemented in the code. You can use it directly as above

Most important, don't forget

```
public virtual string SelectedText { get; set; }
```

This is the complete code with menu item

```
private void Menu_Copy(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Ensure that text is selected in the text box.    
if(textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    // Copy the selected text to the Clipboard.
    textBox1.Copy();
}

private void Menu_Cut(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
 // Ensure that text is currently selected in the text box.    
 if(textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
    // Cut the selected text in the control and paste it into the Clipboard.
    textBox1.Cut();
 }

Private void Menu_Paste(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Determine if there is any text in the Clipboard to paste into the text box. 
if(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
{
    // Determine if any text is selected in the text box. 
    if(textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
      // Ask user if they want to paste over currently selected text. 
      if(MessageBox.Show("Do you want to paste over current selection?", "Cut Example", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
         // Move selection to the point after the current selection and paste.
         textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart + textBox1.SelectionLength;
    }
    // Paste current text in Clipboard into text box.
    textBox1.Paste();
  }
}


private void Menu_Undo(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Determine if last operation can be undone in text box.    
if(textBox1.CanUndo == true)
{
   // Undo the last operation.
   textBox1.Undo();
   // Clear the undo buffer to prevent last action from being redone.
   textBox1.ClearUndo();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!but `if (textbox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
{

}` did not work for me!and would you please tell me where should I write them in textchanged event?

Comment: I've checked it before!Should I write it somewhere else in my code?

Comment: Not necessary. But try this with text_changed event

Comment: Thanks,but nothing happens when I select a text!check my question again  for the code again please

Comment: I know your code works well but the problem is that I don't know where to write`if(textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    // Copy the selected text to the Clipboard.
    textBox1.Copy();`     I dont want to have any extra buttons or controls.Thanks.

Comment: You should create menu items with popup and shortcut keys and write the code under the menus. If you don't want the menu item then set visible=false. So obviously you can work with shortcut keys

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.SelectedText != String.Empty)  
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.SelectedText;
        }


        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            label2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my opinion the easiest way to go with this is to define enabling/disabling method:

```
private void editMenuItemOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //enable copy and cut only if some text is selected
    copyMenuItem.Enabled = cutMenuItem.Enabled = textBox1.SelectionLength > 0;
    //enable paste only if there's some text in the clipboard to paste
    pasteMenuItem.Enabled = Clipboard.ContainsText();
}
```

and attach it to the `editMenuItem.DropDownOpened` event (when using Forms) or `editMenuItem.SubmenuOpened` event (when using WPF; You may also want to use `RoutedEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs` in this case).

Alternatively, if You're using WPF, You could make use of the `textBox1.SelectionChanged` event. It's not present in Forms, so in that case You probably should use a combination of `textBox1.MouseUp` and `textBox1.KeyUp` events.

Answer (score 1):

For the Second half of your question:

```
textbox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);

private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        // enable delete, copy & paste functions
    }
    else
    {
        // disable delete, copy & paste functions
    }
}
```

Comment: I told that when the user selects some text I want to enable copy and paste ...!the code you've written does not match my requirement!

Comment: Ok well I'm sorry that you clarified your question after I had answered. If you want an event to fire after a text selection instead of a text change, then change the TextChangedEventHandler to a RoutedEventHandler: textbox1.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(textbox1_SelectionChanged); As for the if statement: if(textbox1.SelectionLength > 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
        {
            txtTextSelected.Text = textBox1.SelectedText;
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);//This is optional
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = "";
            Clipboard.Clear();//This is optional
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. Just raw code doesn't explain why this works. An explanation would make your answer more useful